# Subclass of UITableView indexPath nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsindexpath

I'm trying to subclass a UITableView. However, I'm unable to get an indexPath that isn't nil. The tableView has custom cells.

Here is my TouchTableView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h> //I brought this in because I'm saving audio files in my app
#import "SimpleTableCell.h"



@protocol myTableViewDelegate;

@interface TouchTableView : UITableView <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, AVAudioRecorderDelegate, AVAudioPlayerDelegate, UITextViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<myTableViewDelegate> myDelegate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *sortedFiles;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *simpleTableIdentifier;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SimpleTableCell *cell;
@property BOOL inverted;

-(void)refreshTable;

@end


@protocol myTableViewDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)selectedFile:(TouchTableView *)tableView withURL: (NSURL *) tableViewURL IndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
-(void)didDelete:(TouchTableView *)tableView IndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
-(void)setSortedFile:(TouchTableView *)tableView;

@end
```

I attach a longpress like so:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //bring in your custom cell here

    simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

            [cell.textField setEnabled:NO];


            //put in long press
            UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:)];
            [longPressGesture setMinimumPressDuration:1.0];

            [cell addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];

        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Then I have the following method for when the longpress activates:

```
- (void)longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    if (![cell.textField isEnabled]) {
        // only when gesture was recognized, not when ended
        if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
        {
            // get affected cell
            cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[gesture view];

            // get indexPath of cell

            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self indexPathForCell:cell];
            [self selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:0];


            [cell.textField setEnabled:YES];
            [cell.textField becomeFirstResponder];


        }
    }
}
```

In my viewController in viewDidLoad I have:

```
self.touchTableView = [[TouchTableView alloc] init];

 [self.tableView setDelegate:self.touchTableView];
 [self.tableView setDataSource:self.touchTableView];

 self.touchTableView.myDelegate = self;
```

The problem is that the indexPath is always nil. You'll note that I'm calling self instead of self.tableView because self is the tableView. Is there a way to get the indexPath?

Comment: What you are doing makes no sense. Why does `TouchTableView` extend `UITableView` when it's not a table view. It's a controller should use a table view. But then your view controller seems to have its own table view and sets that table view's delegate and data source your `TouchTableView` instance. So now you have two table views, both with the same data source and delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the mess all. rmaddy was right. Ridiculous. The solution:

in my ViewController.h I set up:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet TouchTableView *tableView;
```

Then I changed the last code in my example to

```
[self.tableView setDelegate:self.tableView];
[self.tableView setDataSource:self.tableView];  
self.tableView.myDelegate = self;
[self.tableView refreshTable];
```

Now I'm getting the index path.